# wrapping a click event into a *ngIf in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the best way to only use (click) when the screen size is less than 768 px in width using Angular 2. I have 
    (click)="isClassVisible = !isClassVisible;"
 but want to put it in something like 
    *ngIf="screenWidth < 769 {(click)="isClassVisible = !isClassVisible;"}". 
Not sure how to accomplish this in Angular 2. I know that isn't valid. Basically a nav item that has a secondary drop down should expand on hover on a desktop, and contract when mouse leaves. On mobile I want them to click the nav Item to open, but also close it if they click again. I can do it, but I can't figure out how to only make the click event visible in responsive mode.

Answer (score 0):

You really have two approaches:

1) Create 2 separate elements, one with the click event and one without. Then add specific media query enabled classes to each element, where one of them is hidden when screen is < 768px and the other is hidden when screen > 768px

2) On the onclick event call a function in the controller instead of directly setting values in the ng-click expression. In this function in your controller you can do something like check the screen size from the window object using something like (window.innerWidth). This can get tricky sometimes, so you'll have to a do a lot of testing.

I would honestly use the first approach, even though there is technically a repeat in markup its just easier to follow.

Comment: the first way would be my first approach too, just seeing if there was a alternative way in Angular 2

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'clicable'
    , template: `
      <div [clickIf]="clickIf" (value)="val = $event">click on me</div>
      Width: <input [(ngModel)]="width">
      value:
      <div>{{val}}</div>
    `
  })
  export class ClickableComponent {
    clickIf
    width = 200;

    constructor() {
      this.clickIf = obs => obs.filter(value => this.width > 100);
    }

    setWidth(width: number) {
      this.width = +width;
    }
  }

  let id = 0;

  @Directive({
    selector: '[clickIf]'
  })
  export class ClickIfDirective {
    @Input() clickIf;
    @Output() value = new EventEmitter();

    @HostListener('click') click() {
      Observable.of(1).let(this.clickIf).subscribe(val => this.value.next(id++));
    }
  }
```